# showing Load 'name' (-1) couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the built settings even after adding it

Tags: c#, unity

I have created 3 scenes `(StartMenu, Game, Win)` and added all of them to built setting with proper arrangement. `StartMenu` Scene has a button `start` which should take game to second `Game` Scene when onClick event is called on it.

The onClick event of `start` button is mapped to `LevelManager` Empty Object. That object has a script `LevelManager` whose code I have posted.

I have added all those scenes to built settings.[image]

but still I am getting this error:

```
Level 'name'(-1) couldn't be loaded because it has been added to the built settings.
To add a level to the built settings use menu File->Built settings.
UnityEngine.Application:LoadLevel(String)
LevelManager:LoadLevel(String) (at Assets/Scripts/LevelManager.cs:8) // 8 line is Application.LoadLevel line)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

**LevelManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public void LoadLevel(string name){
            Application.LoadLevel(name);
    }

    public void QuitRequest(){
            Debug.Log("Quit Requested"); 
    }

}
```

Error Code snapshot(couldn't copy):[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste the error message instead of trying to retype it. You've changed the meaning of the message with mistakes.

Comment: @Byte56 i couldn't copy it...so have uploaded the screenshot. Please have a look at it.

Comment: What is the exact string you are passing to LoadLevel? Debug it.

Comment: -1. You should at least try to debug your code before asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message tells you exactly what is wrong. You are trying to load scene with name `name`. You have to change the string in the editor in OnClick handler to `Game` in your case.

Comment: yaa you are 100% correct. But, I don't it clearly in error message. Which line that's it?

Comment: First line, second word. It's not variable name but variable value. Change text to `dumb` and you will notice the difference in error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It worked one day, and not the next. I found that for some reason, it lost the link in the picture I provided. It worked fine after I updated all of the buttons on all of the scenes.

[image: Screenshot]